# Customizing buttons in p5js with DOM

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to customize a button using the p5js DOM library.

I have looked at the p5js reference and other sources, but there doesn't seem to be anything there.

```
var button;
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(100, 100);
    background(0);
    button = createButton('click me');
    button.position(19, 19);
    button.mousePressed(changeBG);
  }
  function changeBG() {
    var val = random(255);
    background(val);
  }
```

What I want is a way to give the button a color or change the size of the button if that is possible (the code above just makes a button that changes the background of the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using classes and .css file as usual. There is the method [`class()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/class) to do so. Or in the code directly you can manipulate DOM elemnt properties. There are several built in methods, but the DOM element can always be accessed by: [`.elt`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/elt) like calling `button.elt` the DOM element is at your disposal so you can call any normal HTML methods on this.

A little example with your code:

```js
  var css_b, val = 71;
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(100, 100);
    background(0);
    css_b = createButton('click me');
    css_b.position(19, 19);
    css_b.style('background-color: #D6B5DD;')
    css_b.mouseOver(()=>css_b.style('background-color: #D35DEB;'));
    css_b.mouseOut(()=>css_b.style('background-color: #D6B5DD;'));
    css_b.mousePressed(changeBG);
  }

function draw() {
  background(val);
}

  function changeBG() {
     val = random(255);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step one:** Learn about CSS. Here are a few resources:

- [CSS - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)
- [CSS - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)
- [CSS - HappyCoding](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/html/css) (disclaimer: I wrote this)

**Step two:** Use the `style()` function from P5.dom to apply CSS styling to your elements. You can find more info [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/style).

Note that you don't need to use P5.dom to use CSS styling. I'd recommend playing around with a simplified example that doesn't use P5.dom first.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I know CSS. I just didn't know how to apply it to p5js